# Git commands fatal errors even with .git present

Tags: git, ubuntu-18.04

I am not sure what has happened, but git on the command line (Ubuntu 18.04) is not behaving.

When I am in my local repo space and check the status I get this

```
git status
fatal: not a git repository: ''
```

When I look at the directory structure, I see the .git directory and inside the git files.
HEAD is `ref: refs/heads/master`

When I try and re-init git I get this

```
git init
fatal: The empty string is not a valid path
```

I have even deleted the workspace directory and `git clone` to pull the repo back from the remote source and I still get this weird issue with git.

When I move out of my workspace directory and create a directory elsewhere, and try and `git init` I get the above fatal error message as well.

BUT...
When I use vscode with GitLens, it works without an issue and vscode can see the repo and commits on that repo etc.

I am not sure what has happened to my git install. I was at, I think, 2.34 via a PPA. I purged the PPA and downgraded back to 2.17 (which is the latest that Ubuntu 18.04 technically supports)

I am wondering if some other library might be stopping git on the command line to be working correctly?

Comment: Try creating a new user and seeing if Git works for it, to rule out any local configuration and state (`~/.gitconfig`, shell aliases, etc.).

Comment: Are there any `GIT*` variables set in your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the [`GIT_DIR`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDIRcode) environment variable is set to `''`. If `GIT_DIR` exists, git will use it to find the .git directory.

```
$ GIT_DIR='' git status
fatal: not a git repository: ''
$ GIT_DIR='' git init
fatal: The empty string is not a valid path
```

Unset that environment variable. How you do this depends on your shell.

Comment: I'm going to have to say this is the answer.
Our build requires the use of GIT_DIR, but --git-dir was removed in a newer version of Git (due to quirkiness apparently) so I did have a GIT_DIR env var in my shell after I downgraded back to git 2.17. 

It started working properly this morning (not sure what happened between yesterday and today, but perhaps the shell never reloaded properly after a `. ~/.profile` execution until I logged back in this morning.